# Retrieve orientation change event in blackberry webworks?

Tags: javascript, orientation, blackberry-webworks

1) How to retrieve orientation change event in blackberry webworks ?

2) Can we change orientation programmatically at runtime using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There is a KB here for retrieving orientation change events:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Detect-screen-orientation-changes-using-JavaScript/ta-p/445755

Alternatively, you could listen for window.onresize.

You can not change the orientation programmatically at this time, but you can at compile time through the rim:orientation property:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/rim_orientation_element_1594186_11.html